# Counting a left join depending on other left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT options.id, options.text, 
COUNT(options2.id) AS num_children
FROM options
JOIN history_uids AS uids
    ON uids.uid = options.id
LEFT JOIN options AS options2
    ON (options.id = options2.id_parent)
LEFT JOIN history_uids AS uids1
    ON uids1.uid = options2.id
WHERE (
options.id = 25
AND (uids1.active = 1 OR
options2.id IS NULL) # Problem
)
GROUP BY `options`.`id`
```

There is an `options` table, and another, `history_uids`, which has a column named `uid` with the id of every options, and an `active` column set to 1 or 0.

I am expecting to get a result with:

1. The ID and the text of the option which has the `id` 25, and which has `active` set to 1 in `history_uids`.
2. The number of options which have an `id_parent` equal to the `id` (25) and for which `active` in `history_uids` is set to 1

So whatever is this number I should get my row if it has `active` set to 1. I cannot understand how to achieve this: I wanna set as last condition `uids1.active = 1 OR "options2 doesn't exist"`, but to get this I should have my `active` condition in the `ON` of `options2`, which is not possible because at that moment the table `history_uids` is not yet referenced...

In my case the row has `active` set to 1 and has 5 children with `active` set to 0, so I should get my row with `num_children` set at 0. Instead whatever combination I do in the `JOIN` or the `WHERE` I get either `num_children` set to 5 or no result at all.

Thanks for your help (and for reading!)

Here is the full structure and data for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE `history_uids` (
  `uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `history_uids` (`uid`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 0),
(3, 0),
(4, 0),
(5, 0),
(6, 0);
CREATE TABLE `options` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `options` (`id`, `id_parent`, `text`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'parent active'),
(2, 1, 'child 1 inactive'),
(3, 1, 'child 2 inactive'),
(4, 1, 'child 3 inactive'),
(5, 1, 'child 4 inactive'),
(6, 1, 'child 5 inactive');
ALTER TABLE `history_uids`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`);
ALTER TABLE `options`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id_parent` (`id_parent`);
ALTER TABLE `options`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parent`) REFERENCES `options`     (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `history_uids` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `COUNT(options2.id)` only counts non-null values, so the rows where `options2.id IS NULL` won't be counted.

Comment: Can you show some example input and the desired result? I suspect what you need is two queries that you combine with `UNION`, but it's hard to understand your description.

Comment: I have added structure and data if you want to test the query. The goal is to get the row with `num_children` set at `0` (as all child options have the corresponding  `history_uids.active` set to 0)

Comment: @Barmar I would like this as a result: `{id: 1, text: 'parent active', num_children: 0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `active` test for the child row into the `ON` clause, so that inactive rows will be filtered out of the `LEFT JOIN`. And you should be counting `uids1.uid`, not `options2.id`, since the inactive rows aren't filtered out until you join with `uids1`.

```
SELECT options.id, options.text, 
    COUNT(uids1.uid) AS num_children
FROM options
JOIN history_uids AS uids
    ON uids.uid = options.id
LEFT JOIN options AS options2
    ON (options.id = options2.id_parent)
LEFT JOIN history_uids AS uids1
    ON uids1.uid = options2.id and uids1.active = 1
WHERE 
uids.active = 1
GROUP BY `options`.`id`
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf5819/9)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wanted to keep my count as it was but your solution counting the uids helped me found what I wanted: I added another join on the same table before and counted my original join with your last condition: `ON uids1.uid = options2.id and uids1.active = 1`